# How to manage cname, MX and Azure

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, mx-record, azure, subdomain

I am hosting my domain at 1&1 and have a VM and a mobile service in Azure. Currently I have set a cname to xxx.cloudapp.net. Now I want to create a subdomain for my Azure mobile service (something like mobile.mydomain.net instead of xxx.mobile-azure.net).

I would also need the ability to set MX records.

Hopefully someone of you can help me solving this problem :)

Michi

Answer (score 0):

Just create cname which will point to your cloudapp:

```
mobile.mydomain.net -> xxx.cloudapp.net
```

Your application will be able to distinguish between `mydomain.net` and `mobile.mydomain.net`.

Comment: Where can I create my subdomain? the 1&1 control panael has no options for that and where can I enter my MX records? Needed for outlook.com with own domain :)

Comment: Strange.. I found one support ticket in Google: http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317#1and1 . It describes how to create a subdomain. Maybe it will help.

Comment: MX records should be added there too: http://faq.1and1.co.uk/domains/domain_admin/dns_settings/9.html

Comment: Subdomain: I have a only domain package and I can't access this feature!

Comment: MX records: but then I have to use A-record and not cname

Comment: In that case you'll have to upgrade.

Comment: To what should I upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Create an A record for your subdomain and then create a cname from subdomain.mydomain.net to xxx.mobile-azure.net

Comment: Where can I create my subdomain? the 1&1 control panael has no options for that

Comment: Where can I enter my MX records? Needed for outlook.com with own domain :)

Comment: where did you setup your first cname for xxx.cloudapp.net? It's in the same nameserver registry. You should be able to add an mx record that point to your mail host in there too, but I know 1&1 give you an option to enter your mx record in the setup when you configure it and probably don't need to enter it in the nameserver records.

Comment: When configuring your outlook you don't need the mx record you need the mailhost name with your account name on their service to connect to it. The mx record on your nameserver will redirect mail that target your domain name to your mailhost which will make you receive email in your outlook mail box.

Comment: The first cname I entered at the 1&1 control panel. The MX record is just available if I choose A-record.

Comment: In some contracts 1&1 only allows MX entries for A records in the same zone. So you will no be lucky with Office 365 in such.